# Candles for praying at home

Tags: tefilla

In schul we light candles before starting davening. If someone is praying at home, can they light candles as well (without a minian)? Does it have to be two? Or one is sufficient to remember the Ner HaTamid?

Comment: What do you mean "can we"? Is it forbidden? Why would it be forbidding? Do you mean "should we"? Also I don't think people light candles for the ner hatamid

Comment: "In schul we light candles before starting davening" should say "In schul, before electricity was invented,  we lit candles before starting davening." Since then, many of us have given up this dangerous useless activity.